# Prim’s MST Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I just finished an exercise on the application of Prim's theorem. However, I don't have the solution to this problem, but I found an answer in this exercise.
Could someone verify that the solution I got is correct ?
Here is the statement:[image]

Thanks in advance !

For this exercise I found the following sequence:
B-C, B-H, H-A, A-I, I-F, F-G, G-E, E-D
Total cost: 2+3+7+4+5+1+9+17 = 48

Comment: There seems to be an error on the last edge. The solution adds E-D at a cost of 17 while G-D has a cost of 14.

Comment: @beaker Yes, your’re right. Thanks for your fast answer !